# Taking result of a grep search and using it to search another file. linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to search the file dep/playlist for 'ohn'. Then, I would like to take this result and apply it to a new grep command that searches the file employee list end then echoes the results on screen. The code below isn't behaving as expected.

```
grep ohn dep/playlist > search
grep $(cat search) employeelist > newlist
cat newlist
```

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `grep` to obtain the patterns from a file, use the `-f` option:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

So the command would look like:

```
grep -f search employeelist > newlist
```

Using process substitution you could obviate the need of a temporary file.  So the two `grep` commands could be written into one as:

```
grep -f <(grep ohn dep/playlist) employeelist > newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

[xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

```
grep ohn dep/playlist | xargs -I name grep name employeelist
```

This searches `dep/playlist` for 'ohn', and then upon finding a result, that result is then used in `grep X employeelist`, where `X` is the result from the first grep.

Comment: I would suggest adding `-n 1` option to `xargs`.